# Devexpress : Adding XRChart to detail band dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I want to add `XRChart` to detail band dynamically. I have a `DetailBand` which its name is "Detail". And here is my code:

```
ChartControl pointChart = new ChartControl();
testReport.Detail.Controls.Add(pointChart);
```

But it says:
[image]

What should I do to add that Chart Control dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong class. You want to use `XRChart`, so use it:

```
var pointChart = new XRChart();
testReport.Detail.Controls.Add(pointChart);
```

But if you want to use `ChartControl` class then you need to use `PrintableComponentContainer`:

```
var pointChart = new ChartControl();

var container = new PrintableComponentContainer();
container.PrintableComponent = pointChart;

testReport.Detail.Controls.Add(container);
```